# How to exclude certain years from a year(column) result?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Given the following code:

```
SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS y, count(ID) as posts_count
FROM fdr_posts p
WHERE 
    p.post_status = 'publish' 
    OR p.post_status = 'future' 
    AND p.post_type = 'event'
GROUP BY y
ORDER BY post_date ASC
```

How can I exclude from column y certain years? So, every year except say, 2016 and 2017?

Comment: include it in the `where` clause.

Comment: Be cautious of your `or` w/o ()'s  perhaps use IN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE 
p.post_status IN ( 'publish' , 'future' ) 
AND p.post_type = 'event'
AND YEAR(p.post_date) NOT IN (2016,2017)
```